# How to select the div that occupies more space in the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Situation**-

I have number of block elements `div(s)` in my document. Where each one of them is relatively aligned.

I would want to select the one that occupies more space in the viewport than it's sibling blocks on scroll.

See in image-

[image]

I tried-

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.container div').each(function(){
      if(isVisible($(this), $(window))){
      console.log($(this).attr('class')+" is visible");
      };  
  });
});
```

**Calculating** `offset`

```
function isVisible( block, container ){

    var elementTop = $(block).offset().top,
        elementHeight = $(block).height(),
        containerTop = container.scrollTop(),
        containerHeight = container.height();

    return ((((elementTop - containerTop) + elementHeight) > 0) && ((elementTop - containerTop) < containerHeight));
}
```

Now if you note in console, I am displaying block which is visible on screen. Now when two or more blocks are visible on screen then only the one that occupies more space in the viewport.

Currently, It is selecting both blocks. I have no idea how do I approach with it now.

Here you find the fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/13odrk4t/

Comment: most visible = ? please provide a **solid** definition.

Comment: get visible portion of screen X,Y to X+visible_width,Y+visible_height cycle through all your visible elements find their X,Y and X+width,Y+height area, and calc the area that overlaps with visible portion of screen (viewport). if visible element overlap each other do for every element the same check and negate overlapping area if it has lower z-index than other overlaping element. now someone can code this as an answer i guess. of course all this must calculated on pagescroll or something.

Comment: The block of color green in image above is more visible than the below one, I want to select that green one. vice-versa the purple one.

Comment: this is not a solid definition. what do you mean more visible? the one that occupies more space in the viewport? (that's what i assumed on my previous comment)

Comment: @KatrinRaimond, Yes exactly!

Comment: nice! then i think my comment will work, hopefully someone will code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental part of the problem you are having is that you are trying to determine the most viewable item but you are only checking the visibility on each element. Instead you need to be able to compare the percent of the viewable space taken up by each block and find the maximum.  So conceptually this looks like

1. For each element get the percentage taken up
2. Compare each percentage, keeping the one that takes up more percentage of the space
3. At the end of the sequence of elements you have the maximum value and do what you need.

In a more functional pseudo code way I think of this as something like

```
elements.map( e => (e, percentTaken(e)).fold(None)((max, ep) => if (max == None or max.percent < ep.percent) ep else max))
```

Here is the fiddle of how I solved it. I think it gives you what you want but probably can use some clean-up to make it more idiomatic and the logic in getting the percentage cleaner
https://jsfiddle.net/7s95a4nn/